# what is the best way for fetch some data from mysql via php functions without many query excute in one page

Tags: php, mysql, function, connection

i don't know what is the best way for fetching some data from different tables via php functions
my database is mysql .
i have 3 file !

- config.php (infromation about database configuration)
- functions.php (my php functions for fetching data from database -
  config.php included in this file)
- index.php

---

config.php source code:

```
    class dbinformation{
        public $db_hostname = 'localhost';
        public $db_username = 'root';
        public $db_password = '';
        public $db_name = 'alireza_mirhabibi';
        public $db_prefix = 'cms_';
        public $db_charset = 'utf-8';
}
```

---

functions.php source code is similar to below :

```
    require_once('config.php');         
    function connection(){
        $db_cms= new dbinformation();
        $hname=$db_cms->db_hostname; /*Host Name*/
        $uname=$db_cms->db_username; /*User Name*/
        $pswd=$db_cms->db_password; /*Password*/
        $dname=$db_cms->db_name; /*Database Name*/
        $dbp=$db_cms->db_prefix; /*Database Prefix*/
        $dbc=$db_cms->db_charset; /*Database Charset*/
        $cms_db=mysql_connect($hname,$uname,$pswd);
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $cms_db);
        $selectdb=mysql_select_db($dname,$cms_db);
            if(!$cms_db){
                die ('cms unable to connect server');}
            if(!$selectdb){
                die('Database Not Found !');}
            if($selectdb){
                return $cms_db; }}
```

also in this file (functions.php) i have two function for executing query from mysql , similar to below :

```
function cms_title($close){
    $title_cms=mysql_query("select title from cms_global where id='1'");
    while($fetch_title=mysql_fetch_array($title_cms)){
    echo $fetch_title['title'];}
    mysql_close($close);
}

function cms_footer($close){
    $footer_cms=mysql_query("select footer from cms_footer where id='1'");
    while($fetch_footer=mysql_fetch_array($footer_cms)){
    echo $fetch_footer['footer'];}
    mysql_close($close);
}
```

---

i used top functions in index.php file for fetch 2 string in separate place of my index.php file
you can see the index.php source code at below :

```
<?php

    include('functions.php');

    $clo=connection();
    cms_title($clo);

    $clo=connection();
    cms_footer($clo);

?>
```

---

but my questions :

1. this programming model is correct ?
2. what is the best way for define functions for executing mysql query
   via php ?i want to have fast loading in my pages with execute many query (fastest way for functional query executing)
3. do you have any idea or style for this job ?

special thanks

Comment: It's not "incorrect", but it's also not "good". There is **NO** reason to close your mysql connection after ever single query. that's hideously inefficient. You should connect ONCE at the start of your script, use that connection however many times, then close it when you're completely done with DB operations.

Comment: Thanks for helping 
then i must remove mysql_close() from all functions ? similar to : ? 
    cms_title();
    cms_footer();
and create a simple function for executing in the footer of per page ?
such as : 

function cms_close($clo){
mysql_close($clo);}

index.php source codes :

    $clo=connection(); //open the connection
    cms_title(); // function 1
    cms_footer(); // function 2
    other functions and 
    cms_close($clo); // close connection
this model of programming is right ?